# Sync bookmarks between Safari and Firefox on same MacOS?

Tags: safari, firefox, bookmarks

Is it possible to have same set of merged bookmarks in Safari and Firefox on same local MacOS?

Comment: +1 for this. I’ve been looking for a solution for this. If the solution could do Brave and Microsoft Edge too, that would be great!

Comment: #METOO  :)   it's a great idea: one common bookmarks database that all browsers use. But as I've looked for it off-and-on for years without success, I've become resigned to believe that it 'ain't gonna' happen'.